# Java: Instantiate a concrete impl by name

Tags: java, generics, reflection, dependency-injection

If I have a class named `Widget` then I can create a new one with the following code (more or less):

```
Class<?> widgetClass = Class.forName("Widget");
Widget widget = (Widget)widgetClass.newInstance();
```

But what if I have an interface, `Fruit`, and several concrete implementations (such as `Apple`, `Orange` and `Kiwi`)? If I try:

```
Class<?> fruitClass = Class.forName("Apple");
Fruit fruit = (Fruit)fruitClass.newInstance();
```

I get an error:

> Fruit cannot be resolved to a type.

If I remove the explicit casting like so:

```
Fruit fruit = fruitClass.newInstance();
```

I get a different error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#2-of ? to Fruit.

**So how do I use a String to instantiate the right `Fruit` concretion I want**?

Answer (score 2):

You probably just forgot to import the Fruit interface:

```
import com.foo.bar.Fruit;
```

Note: **NEVER** use the default package. Always put your classes in a package.

Other note: if the name of the class is not read dynamically from some external resource (a file, a database, whatever), but is hard-coded as shown in your question, you should simply invoke its constructor:

```
Fruit f = new Apple();
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message "Fruit cannot be resolved to a type" means that your imports/buildpath are set up incorrectly.

Otherwise, it looks like your code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code.  however, your Fruit class is not in the compilation classpath, hence the compiler error.